# new Query database when change option field

Tags: php, mysql, html-select, onchange, reload

I have an intial group of options like these:

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
    <option value="waktupesan">Waktu Pesan</option>
    <option value="nomornota">Nomor Nota</option>
    <option value="U.nama">Kasir</option>
</select>
```

And I have to run Query like these:

```
SELECT P.NomorNota, P.WaktuPesan, P.WaktuBayar, P.Total, U.Nama, MP.Nama
FROM foodie.pemesanan P, foodie.user U, foodie.mode_pembayaran MP
WHERE P.EmailKasir = U.Email AND P.Mode = MP.Kode
ORDER BY $sortBy DESC;
```

in value $sortBy I want to get from option value. How to change that query when I change an option value but don't reload page?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Use onchange html attribute to trigger select change, and then use ajax to send http request without reloading page.

Comment: to show data in database and sort by descending in value $sortBy

Comment: Share more detail about how you submit request and where and how you reach to this mysql query by post or by ajax ?

Comment: that change when I change the value in option. I'm just when I change a value in option I get that value in variable $sortBy, but without reload page.

Comment: I mean store the value to $sortBy

Answer (score 1):

You can try jQuery - a javascript library. Download it [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

So assuming you display your data like this ():

```
echo '<table id="data">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Nomor Nota</th>
                  <th>Waktu Pesan</th>
                  <th>Waktu Bayar</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                  <th>U Nama</th>
                  <th>MP Nama</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>';

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>
              <td>'.$nomornota.'</td>
              <td>'.$waktupesan.'</td>
              <td>'.$waktubayar.'</td>
              <td>'.$total.'</td>
              <td>'.$unama.'</td>
              <td>'.$mpnama.'</td>
          </tr>'
}

echo '    </tbody>
      </table>';
```

Then your select field:

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
    <option selected disabled>Select Sort</option>
    <option value=0>Nomor Nota</option>
    <option value=1>Waktu Pesan</option>
    <option value=2>Waktu Bayar</option>
    <option value=3>Total</option>
    <option value=4>U Nama</option>
    <option value=5>MP Nama</option>
</select>
```

We now have to create a script sort our table.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- ASSUMING YOU STORE THE DOWNLOADED JQUERY TO A js FOLDER -->
<script>

    $(document).on("change", "select", function(){ /* WHEN SELECT FIELD HAS BEEN CHANGED TO THE PREFERRED SORT */

        var no = $(this).val(); /* VALUE OF THE SELECTED SORT */
        sortTable(no); /* CALL sortTable() FUNCTION */

    });

    function sortTable(no){ /* sortTable() FUNCTION */

        var rows = $('#data tbody tr').get(); /* GET ROWS OF INSIDE TBODY */

        rows.sort(function(b, a) { /* USE JAVASCRIPT'S .sort() */

            var A = $(a).children('td').eq(no).text().toUpperCase();
            var B = $(b).children('td').eq(no).text().toUpperCase();

            if(A < B) {
                return -1;
            }

            if(A > B) {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;

        });

        $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
            $('#data').children('tbody').append(row); /* APPEND THE NEW SORT OF DATA TO THE TABLE */
        });
    }

</script>
```

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/3g7Lnew8/) for an example.